# Access container's port from on eIP

Tags: docker, ufw, wireguard

I have three servers that are in same network via WireGuard.
Their IPs are:

- 10.10.10.1
- 10.10.10.2
- 10.10.10.3

I have a docker container on 10.10.10.1 that give me service on port 8080/tcp.
I want 10.10.10.2 to be allowed connect to it but not 10.10.10.3.

I exposed my container port with `-e 10.10.10.1:8080:8080` then add below ufw role:

```
ufw allow from 10.10.10.2 to 10.10.10.1 port 8080 proto tcp
```

But 10.10.10.3 still can access to this port.

Comment: what do you see when running `ufw status verbose`

Comment: ```Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)   ```